# How do you make a table and refer to it using the value of a variable?

Tags: lua

I want to make a table which is called *the value of another variable* and then refer to it that way. Here’s some code so you sort of understand.

```
example = 123 # the variable i’m using

example = { } # create a table which is actually called 123

example[“abc”] = 789
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Any help please!!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. What you are doing is setting the variable `example` to the value `123` and then setting it to the value `{}`. After you set it to the value `{}`, it no longer has the value `123`. There's no way to create a table that is "actually called 123" because tables don't have names, but you can add a `name` field to the table by doing `example.name = 123`. What is the purpose you want to achieve by giving the table a name though?

Comment: I'm trying to make a separate table for each user on the fly, with their user ID as the name of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd have some kind of a table for all your users.

The global environment is also just a normal Lua table, but you don't want to pollute it by creating new variable for every user.

So your example might look like this:

```
-- global container of users
all_users = {} 

-- update existing user with new data
local userID = 123
local user = all_users[userID] -- find user
user.abc = 789

-- create new user
local userID = 777
local new_user = {abc = 789, def = 321} -- some initial data
all_users[userID] = new_user
```